# Parse cloud code issue accessing pointers in request

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

I am having an issue accessing some objects in cloud code.
I am trying to send a push to array of users everytime a message object is save on parse. Here is the beginning of my code :

```
// To send push whenever a message is sent
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Message", function(request) {
  // Our "Comment" class has a "text" key with the body of the comment itself
  var messageText = request.object.get('text');
  var messageUserFirstName = request.object.get('user').get('firstName');

  var usersId = [];
  var conversation = request.object.get('conversation').get('group1').get('users');
```

In my Message table, I have a pointer to the class Conversation, which has also a pointer to a class Group, which contains an array of Users pointers. It seems I cannot access this array with the following line:

```
  var conversation = request.object.get('conversation').get('group1').get('users');
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'user', 'conversation', and 'group1' objects will all need to be fetched before you can access their data.